# Can anyone help me to get math.round() to get the following output

Tags: .net, vb.net, rounding

DecimalValue = (Math.Round(varDecimal /8, 1)

The value of 'varDecimal' will keep change but in the output after decimal i only need #.0 or #.5

for example

9/8 =1.1    --> but I need this 1.5
11/8 =1.4   --> but I need this 1.5
21/8 =2.6   --> but I need this 3.0
27/8 =3.4   --> but I need this 3.5
33/8 =4.1   --> but I need this 4.5
39/8 =4.9   --> but I need this 5.0
45/8 =5.6   --> but I need this 6.0

The idea is after decimal above 0 should be rounded to .5 and above .5 should be rounded 1

Comment: Use `Decimal.Round` it will yield what you need.

Answer (score 4):

This is what it looks like in C#, but it should be easy to port to VB.Net:

http://goo.gl/ztLJC2

```
Math.Ceiling((double)value * 2) / 2
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try using this tiny method.

```
Public Function Round(num As Double) As Double
    Dim intVal =  CInt(Math.Truncate(num))
    Dim remainder = num - intVal

    If remainder = 0 Then
        Return num

    ElseIf remainder <= 0.5 Then

        remainder = 0.5


        Return (intVal + remainder)
    Else


        intVal += 1


        Return CDbl(intVal)
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: Your function result with `6.5` calculating`45/8`

Comment: @nelek i'm getting 6 with the c# version ... not sure if it can be different

Comment: Your `intVal=Cint(num)` return `6` instead `5` ... function already round to one upper int, because result is 5.625

Comment: @nelek I've seen the issue .. fixed. Thanks. Didn't really test in vb.net till you pointed it out :)

Comment: No prob. It would be unfair to provide Your solution fixing just that issue ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use `Math.Ceiling()`

```
Math.Ceiling(value)
//Do your computations to get the .5
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zx4t0t48(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score -2):

this should work: math.round((value*2)+0.5)/2)